# Infopath 2010 TextArea not wrapping text, browser view source reveals "white-space: pre"

Tags: textarea, whitespace, infopath, word-wrap

I have a strange problem with InfoPath 2010. It seems that when using a text with multiline the default formatting will be "white-space: pre" which prevents the text to break at the end of the field. It will only break if enter is manually pressed.

In my case, this is not acceptable. I do not know if it is possible to attache any CSS with my form. This would of course solve my problem.

[image]

Any other ideas that could help me crack this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had to solve this quickly so I had to do it the "ugly" way... I opened the xsl-files that had the problem and added the following code:

```
  <style>
     textarea{
        white-space: normal !important;
     }
  </style>
```

Then I right-clicked on my "manifest.xsf", selected "design" and published... And voilà!

Let's hope the form won't break later due to those changes. (Hint: Always back up your code before doing changes to the source-files in InfoPath)...

Answer (score 0):

You can open view*.xsl from this form package and replace current control css from **"WHITE-SPACE: NORMAL"**  to "**WHITE-SPACE: pre-line !important;"**.
In this way you don't need add any css file and it works fine for O365 as well.
Only small issues: then you edit form in the Infopath designer this textaria doesn't look pretty but it only on designer.

Comment: Why would pre-line be better than normal? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: the Infopath  transformation not always understandably.   And style "WHITE-SPACE:NORMAL"  become  "WHITE-SPACE:pre" in a page.